# Обработка строк : Pandas

Tags: строки, pandas

Есть некая Series данных, например:

Нижний Новгород
Нижний Новгород
Москва
Дзержинск
Арзамас
607600 Нижегородская обл Кстовский р н Кстово г Ломоносова ул дом № 0
Ярославль
Юбилейный
607700 Нижегородская область Кстовский район город Кстово пр Победы 00
Нижний новгород
600600 Нижегородская обл Кстовский р н Кстово г Центральное ш дом
Балахна
Г. Бор
Саров
Городец
Бор
Муром
600 600 Нижний Новгород улица Минина дом 0
Заволжье
г Нижний Новгород
Богородск
Арзамас
Чебоксары
Гороховец
Москва
РОССИЯ 600600 Нижегородская обл Кстовский р н Кстово г Промышленный р н Центральное ш дом № 0
Нижегородская область
Сергач
Кстово
607700 НИЖЕГОРОДСКАЯ ОБЛАСТЬ КСТОВСКИЙ РАЙОН ДЕРЕВНЯ АНКУДИНОВКА
607800 г Арзамас ул Короленко 100
Школьная 53
Дзержинск Нижегородская обл. бульвар Космонавтов д. 0 А , кв. 0
Дзержинск г Терешковой ул дом № 0 кв 0
603300 Нижний Новгород Серова 0
РОССИЯ 606600Нижегородская обл Вачский муниципальный район сельское поселение Новосельский   сельсовет Новоселки с Гагарина ул дом № 0
Арзамас, проспект Ленина, дом 0
606330 Нижегородская обл г Дзержинск ул Попова д 0 кв 00

Как можно такую серию привести в вид типа: Индекс, Область, город, улица, дом, квартира ??

Например встречается 'Нижний Новгород', но где то написан как 'Нижний Новгород', а где то как 'Нижний Новгород ' или вообще 'Нижний Новгорд'

Comment: пока напрашивается сделать некий словарь, куда добавить города например, потом наверное отдельный словарь на поселки и села